# Как настроить сайдбар в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день. Подключила 2 сайдбара в Wordpress. Соответственно нужно чтобы они были слева и справа. Вопрос в том чтобы динамически менялся размер центральной части в зависимости от того выбран один, либо оба сайдбара. Вот тут проблема, что то сильно туплю. Помогите советом или полезной ссылочкой.

Answer (score 1):

> Помогите советом или полезной ссылочкой.

В зависимости от того как и где подключается.

http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile

http://htmlbook.ru/css/media

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, вы меня немного не правильно поняли. Если я в админке выберу один сайдбар, нужно чтобы центральная часть занимала 75%. Если 2, то 50%. И вопрос был в том как сделать чтобы автоматически использовались необходимый набор правил. Мне подошел такой вариант https://kolakube.com/wordpress-layout-options/

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь что вам придется не много поработать в шаблоне он у вас не резиновый похоже

Как вариант найти в css класс 
.sideba-left и присвоить display:none;(в зависимости от темы)
Это должно убрать все левую полосу

Можно посмотреть тут

http://senka.ru/2009/12/14/dorabotka-shablona-dlia-wp-nalilnikom/

Comment: Не надо такое ни читать ни давать. "Шаблоны", блин..."поуглить их".. "в сеть за новым шаблоном".  И пост сам 2009г..

Comment: если подключают сайдбары, значит тема уже выбрана, и менять тему возможно утопие

Comment: Про замену темы никто не говорил. Хотя это может быть и будет лучше.